# Is there a vb.net method similar to the old basic field function

Tags: vb.net, split, data-extraction, string-function

I have a string of numbers separated by spaces. I want to add each number to an array. The string of numbers is in a textbox text property.

The syntax for the old field function is:
`FIELD (string, delimiter, occurrence [ ,num.substr] )`

I tried using the following, but since I have no idea how to use split() it did nothing but return my original string.

```
    Dim nline As String = txtarray.text
    ' Dim separators() As String = txtarray.text
    Dim separators() As String = {"Domain:", "Mode:"}

    Dim result() As String
    result = nline.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I think I have it working... I changed separatoars to:

`Dim separators() As String = {" "}`

and it seems to return the result I am looking for.

Comment: The separator is your empty space between your words. In reality you don't even need to supply a separator to Split because if you don't pass any parameter it automatically splits on whitespaces

Comment: Thank you for that JM.  Did I forget to mention that I am new to  vb.net and am still learning.  I will certainly remember the F1 key in the future.